How do you establish a relationship on a library such that a breaking change in the library forces an update on all dependencies?
Let's say I have two packages and a library, all at version 1.

PackageFoo version 1.
PackageBar version 1.
LibBaz version 1.

Now,

PackageFoo requires LibBaz
PackageBar requires LibBaz

However, let's say at some point LibBaz introduces a BREAKING CHANGE... let's call it Version 2.0. This change is such that we know all prior dependencies on LibBaz version 1.0 will need to be updated.

PackageFoo version 2.0 is shipped concurrently to use the newer version of LibBaz version 2.0
but, LibBaz version 1.0 is known to conflict with PackageFoo prior to version 2.

How do we ensure installing a newer version of LibBaz (version 2.0) will FORCE an update on PackageFoo (ideally all packages that depend on LibBaz version 1) or prevent the update to LibBaz?

The library in this question can not be installed alongside another version of the same library, unlike in C.

Have baz verify the version of foo

Given your constraints, this has to be dealt with entirely in the packaging, without relying on help from the library ecosystem (see further down for traditional practice with shared libraries).
RPM has two main ways of forcing upgrades with another package (I’ll ignore Requires(meta) which isn’t appropriate in this case):

All dependent packages can specify a maximum version on their dependency — so PackageFoo and PackageBar would both specify Requires: LibBaz < 2. The problem with this is that it requires predicting the future, and only works reliably if all dependent packages specify the version constraint.
The new, incompatible package can conflict with inappropriate versions of dependent packages — so LibBaz would specify Conflicts: PackageFoo < 2. The difficulty here is determining all the dependent packages which are broken by the new version.

The latter is probably your best bet here, but I’m not sure that yum or dnf can correctly resolve this in all cases; it’s possible that they will give up and tell the user there’s a conflict, and leave it up to the user to resolve it (by upgrading LibBaz and PackageFoo simultaneously). The use of “Conflicts” is frowned upon in RPM circles, and this feels like a slight abuse of the declaration. (In .deb packages, there’s explicit support for a “Breaks” declaration which corresponds exactly to this use case.)
Things get easier when the library ecosystem accounts for this. If LibBaz shipped a shared library (.so), this should mostly be dealt with by the library’s soname. LibBaz version 1 would have a soname along the lines of libbaz.so.1, and version 2.0 along the lines of libbaz.so.2.
With this setup, PackageFoo version 1 depends on libbaz.so.1 (not LibBaz version 1 — RPMs handle soname dependencies for shared libraries), and PackageFoo version 2.0 depends on libbaz.so.2. This will force the upgrade in step.
In many cases such an upgrade can’t be dealt with in one shot (uploading LibBaz version 2.0 and rebuilding all the packages that depended on LibBaz version 1), so this would be combined with a slightly renamed package: LibBaz version 1 would be shipped in LibBaz, since the past can’t be changed, but LibBaz version 2.0 would be shipped in LibBaz2. This allows both versions of LibBaz to be installed in parallel. Thanks to the soname change, most programs shouldn’t end up with both versions loaded simultaneously. That will only be a problem if transitive dependencies lead to both packages, and that would have to be dealt with explicitly (in the RPM world, as far as I can determine, by rebuilding the dependencies).
Most ecosystems can emulate something like this by renaming the library with the breaking change — LibBaz would become LibBaz2.

This isn't C, it's Perl. LibBaz is just Baz.pm. This answer seems to depend on the language supporting multiple versions with unique paths, but that's not so. I also think the renaming of the Library would work, but is that really the RPM method of solving this problem? Given semvars, breaking.major.minor every breaking change should result in a new package name for the library?

My crystal ball wasn’t available ;-). Please mention that in your question (LibBaz suggests a C-style .so; Perl modules would be perl-Baz in the RPM world).

Fair response. I didn't want people to get distracted with a solution in Perl, because I'm looking for a solution permitted by RPM. I was aiming for vagueness, but I added the detail in the Q.

That’s understandable, I’ve updated the answer without making it about Perl.

What happens if LibBaz version 2, gets published and claims that it %Conflicts with all versions of the software that reverse-depends on LibBaz version-1?

Why would reverse dependencies be involved?
